# Incrementing value with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, testing

How do I increment value of img path when said path looks like this?

```
//ab[x]/img
```

X value increasing by 1 and has a limit of 50.

Trying to write a test case on how to click on several images on website.

Edit: Just wanted to add that I'm just starting with Selenium IDE and using standart commands.

Comment: Which language are you using? Java?

Comment: Not Java, just starting with Selenium IDE, so I'm using standart Selenium IDE commands and recording my steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1: Format your xpath path selector**

```
for(int i=1; i<=numberOfImages; i++) {
    String path = String.format("//ab[%d]/img", i);
    WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath(path));

    if(image != null) {
        image.click();
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: Select all elements that "//ab/img" returns and iterate over them.**

```
String path = "//ab/img";
List<WebElement> imgElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(path)); //notice the plural
for(WebElement image : imgElements) {
    image.click();
}
```